# Как задать переменную для адреса src в теге embed?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<EMBED TYPE="application/x-mplayer2" 
SRC=filename
filename="путь к файлу"
WIDTH=0 
HEIGHT=0>
```

Comment: Объясните, что Вы хотите сделать. С учетом Вашего предыдущего вопроса, мне кажется, что Вы задаете неправильные вопросы, а значит получите в ответ совсем не то, что Вам нужно.
UPD.  
Да и не понимаю зачем Вам это нужно. Перекодируйте свое видео нормальными кодеками и Вы не столкнетесь с проблемой, что кодек не установлен.

Comment: я хочу ставить музыку в чат со своего компьютера

Comment: откуда программа должна получать переменную?

Comment: Не понятно!

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = /* тут как-то нужно выбрать embed элемент */;
el.src = 'путь к файлу';
// вопрос архи нубский
```

Comment: более того, вопрос уже отвечен =\

Comment: значит так и не будет

Comment: , - Доктор, помогите! У меня что-то болит!
. - Примите что-нибудь.
. - Спасибо, доктор!

Comment: @Portulet Именно, это не вопрос. Я, например, абсолютно не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. @AlexWindHope ответил на вопрос, для более четкого ответа нужен более четкий вопрос. Каким образом прописывается тег embed (js, php, простой html)? Какой id у embed или как еще до него можно добраться? где находится переменная с путем к файлу? 

Мы программисты, а не экстрасенсы. Сейчас вопрос выглядит так: "мне нужно поменять деталь в устройстве, как это сделать?"

Comment: >Помогите! HTML

прошу прощения, но звучит так, как будто этот HTML на вас напал=)